# How can I set S3 ACL parameters with Refile gem integration with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, sendgrid, refile

I am using Refile gem to upload images on S3 with Rails 4. With my current settings, I am able to view the images through S3 URL only after updating the ACL manually.

Is there any way to configure Refile gem to set the ACL params to public_read?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access the images now by updating the S3 bucket policy to this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```